# Getting the key of the object with the lowest value in a hashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

**Some background about my problem:**
I have a People Class with two subclasses: Employee and Customers.  Both classes share the id and name fields. Moreover the Employee class has another field: wage.

I need to get the hashMap key of the object (type Employee) which got the lowest wage... In a hashMap have Employees and Customers objects with some different fields.

Below is the code that I prepared:

```
public String getKeyLowestWage(){
        String k;
        double wage;
        wage = 0;

        Iterator it = ppl.values().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            People s = (People) (it.next() );
            if (s instanceof Employee)
            {
                if ((Employee(getWage()) > wage))
                wage = getWage();
                k = getKey();


            }

        }
        return k;
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I am just a beginner... I am using blueJ (ide)  due to my course requirements....

Comment: @Mureinik  I need to get the key of type Employee that has the lowest wage..... In the Employee class I added getWage() which return the wage of that particular object.

Comment: Stack overflow is a Q&A site. You should ask a question first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the `entrySet()`, which is esentially a collection of key-value pairs:

```
int wage = 0;
String key = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, People> entry : ppl.entrySet()) {
    People s = entry.getValue();
    if (s instanceof Employee) {
        int empWage = ((Employee) s).getWage();
        if (empWage > wage) {
            wage = empWage;
            key = entry.getKey();
        }
    }
}
return key;
```

Comment: thanks for your help :) I am getting: "for-each not applicable to expression type"

Comment: Thanks for your help.... maybe for many it was a stupid question and therefore I got -3 votes... however you answer was very helpful :) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You're testing greater than, not less than. Also, you should use braces.

```
if ((Employee(getWage()) > wage))
    wage = getWage();
    k = getKey();
```

if you indent properly is

```
if ((Employee(getWage()) > wage))
    wage = getWage();
k = getKey();
```

so, something like

```
if ((Employee(getWage()) < wage)) {
    wage = getWage();
    k = getKey();
}
```

should be what you've asked for.

Answer (score 1):

First I think you need some brackets, and you should reverse the comparison:

```
if ((Employee(getWage()) < wage)) {
            wage = getWage();
            k = getKey();
}
```

And of course you need to initialize the value of wage to the biggest possible value:

```
double wage = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```